# Concatenate object property values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JavaScript object. I would like to concatenate all its property values, say:

```
tagsArray["1"] = "one";
tagsArray["2"] = "two";
tagsArray["Z"] = "zed";

result = "one,two,zed"
```

Just for background, I have several checkboxes, and I need to update a hidden selectedKeys field. Example of server side (Asp.Net) code + AngularJS

```
<input hidden id="selectedKeys" value="1,5,8">

@foreach (var tag in tagsDictionary) {
    <input type="checkbox" 
        ng-model="tagsArray['@tag.Key']" 
        ng-true-value  ="'@tag.Key'" 
        ng-false-value ="" 
        ng-change="change(tagsArray)" />@tag.Value
}
```

so on each change I need to update the `#selectedKeys` value

Comment: Can't you just use `name="key[]"` in your checkboxes and have the server receive an array automatically?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. I need a CSV string when I post the form, not an array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var tagsArray = {};
tagsArray["1"] = "one";
tagsArray["2"] = "two";
tagsArray["Z"] = "zed";

var result = Object.values(tagsArray).join(",");
console.log(result); // "one,two,zed"
```

---

More on [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Answer (score 4):

With [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) you can get values as an array, and then just need to pass it to string:

```
Object.values(tagsArray).toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way also,

```
var tagsArray = {};
var result;
tagsArray["1"] = "one";
tagsArray["2"] = "two";
tagsArray["Z"] = "zed";

result = Object.keys(tagsArray).map(function(k){return tagsArray[k]}).join(",");
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for-loop like so:

```
String result = "";
for (var prop in tagsArray) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        result = result + prop + ";";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values()` to access each value in your object and use `join()` to add them together.

```js
var tagsArray = {
  "1" : "one",
  "2" : "two",
  "3" : "zed"
}

var joined = Object.values(tagsArray).join(',');

console.log(joined);
```